# How/From where did the term "paradigm shift" originate?

Tags: etymology

Paradigm Shift + Thinking outside of the box = Death of a Salesman

Comment: Huh? What does Arthur Miller have to do with *paradigm shift*?

Comment: Common sales jargon-speak thrown in just for fun - worth at least a pair a dimes

Comment: That pun is so bad it's not even worth a *thwack*. You should be ashamed of yourself. Hmph.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This term became current with Thomas Kuhn's *The Structure of Scientific Revolutions* (1962): if you Google `"paradigm shift was first used"`, all results confirm that it was first used in that work. He described the same concept in his earlier work *The Copernican Revolution* (1957), but apparently he didn't use the term *paradigm shift* there. It may have existed before Kuhn, but all sources seem to suggest that it did not.

Comment: It might actually occur in Kuhn's earlier book _The Copernican Revolution_

Comment: @Seamus: You're right. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Actually, "paradigm" doesn't appear in the index for The Copernican Revolution and a quick google books search doesn't find any mentions. Sorry. False alarm!

Comment: Also, OED has its first mention as p.66 of _Structure_

Comment: @Seamus: Yeah I have researched it a bit more, and it appears he first used the term (though not the subject) in *Structure*. I have edited my answer again.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Kuhn's writings first mention the idea of paradigm shifts. Somewhere in the *Structure of Scientific Revolutions* he thanks one of his colleagues at UCal Berkley for introducing him to Wittgenstein. He also talks explicitly about Wittgenstein in the beginning of the book--that is, later Wittgenstein. It is clear that Wittgenstein's *On Certainty* is going in the direction of paradigm shifts--i.e. assumptions that are treated as facts. But I'd also check out Koyré's *From the Closed World to the Infinite Universe*--I'm pretty sure Kuhn mentions Koyré in the preface to *SSR.* Although the term paradigm shift wasn't used before Kuhn, the general idea isn't new (I'm thinking of Hume, Kant to an extent, even Protagoras--at least as presented in Plato's *Theaetetus*). --Hope this helps. I'd definitely recommend reading some of these books esp. later Wittgenstein.

Comment: Right, you could very well say that Hume presented a paradigm shift. I think he just didn't consider paradigm shifts on a meta-level as Kuhn did. That is, he may have mentioned that we were stuck with wrong ideas about causality, but I don't remember his musing about the general nature of such shifts in ideas. He might have in some less-well-known paragraph, though.

Comment: That seems right. Though, I was thinking about probability for Hume and assumption for Kant as early examples of a sort of worldview, or perspective, shift (both Hume and Kant were investigating the same thing, but Hume knew not to go too far). Obviously, Koyré pressed the perspective shift before Kuhn, and it seems that Kuhn's paradigm shift owes much to Koyré and Wittgenstein.

Comment: Yeah the history of philosophy is like a living and ageing organism, whose different stages usually develop in gradual steps (though I don't believe it can die or end, as Hegel held).

Comment: --Even Kojève believed in a absolute system of philosophy. But it's unclear exactly how dogmatic of a Hegelian he was, as his *Outline of a Phenomenology of Right* strays a bit from traditional Hegelianism. His friendship with Koyré (and for different reasons Leo Strauss) is rather interesting. But yeah, I would agree that any sort of absolute system of knowledge is nonsensical and is only a product of fact-fudging and dogmatic ignorance--I think it was Bertrand Russel who essentially said as much about Hegel's *Philosophy of History.* --Too bad that philosophy can't get past Plato.

Comment: @Jon: Right, but we philosophers can! I do feel Plato messed up philosophy a bit. It is remarkable that a man like Epicurus emerged from the Academic traditions of transcendentalist Plato and teleologist Aristotle. But he probably owed much to Democritus. Plato is an excellent writer, but too impractical a thinker for my taste.

Comment: Cerberus, I can't agree more. I presume you've read the Kant's *Critique of Pure Reason.* Anyway, do you remember Kant's footnote about Epicurus (I think it was around, or in, one of the Antinomies in the *Transcendental Dialectic*? Essentially, Kant claims that had Epicurus used his skeptical principles solely with regard to reason (and not the understanding), he would have been the greatest philosopher of antiquity--he said something similar to my poor paraphrasing. Descartes' critique of the ancient mathematicians in his *Regulae* seems to accurately assess ancient esotericism in general.

Answer (score 0):

"Paradigm" is a Latin transliteration of the Greek "παράδειγμα", which in current Greek means example, but, in ancient and pre-modern Greek can also mean "general template" or "framework". Plato used the word "παράδειγμα" among many other words, including "ιδέα" (idea) and "μορφή" (form) to describe his General Theory Of The Forms, which used to be called General Theory Of Ideas in past usage of English. It makes perfect sense for Thomas Samuel Kuhn, a scholar and thinker very much at home in physics as well as Greek philosophy, to have picked up "παράδειγμα" from Plato.

Answer (score -3):

As the NOAD reports, the origin of *paradigm shift* is 1970s; the dictionary reports the term was used in the writings of Thomas S. Kuhn.
The *Collins English Dictionary* reports that the origin of the word is the 20th century, and that the term was coined by "T.S. Kuhn (1922-1996), US philosopher of science".

As additional information, the first sentence containing "paradigm shift" reported from the *Corpus of Historical American* is dated 1980-1989.

[image: CoHA]

Comment: No. It was the early 60s

Comment: What I wrote is what the NOAD third edition reports.

Comment: Then that's a downvote for NOAD

Comment: @Seamus: It's not said the NOAD is wrong; there is a difference between when a word was first used in a book, and when the word started to be considered part of a dictionary. I could write a word in a book published on 1986, but that word could have been considered part of the dictionary (which means, the word started to be used from other people too) only since 1996.

Comment: @kiamlaluno The _origin_ of the phrase is in Kuhn's use of it in 1962. _Structure_ made a big splash in the philosophy community so I believe it was probably an established phrase very soon after that. As for when it became more widely used I don't know. But that's a separate question to which Kuhn's coining of the phrase is irrelevant.

Comment: @Seamus: In fact, my answer reports the origin of the word is 1970s, which I take is when the phrase become widely used (I don't think dictionaries report as origin of a word the year when two people started to use it); the answer also reports from where the phrase had origin. If my previous answer was not clear, I think it's now clearer.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I believe the OED's policy is to report the _first documented use_ of the word. But only for words that _are actually in use_. So in 1962 the OED wouldn't have had an entry for paradigm shift, even though it had been used. But once it was in wide use, then _its origin dates back to its first use_. This is surely the only way to do things. How would you adjudicate when a word came into "widespread use"?

Comment: @Seamus: The NOAD reports the origin of the phrase is 1970s. Do you classify a question not useful because it reports what can be found in a different dictionary? Does that mean the OED is more authoritative than the NOAD?

Comment: @kiamlaluno I think you are just wrong that the NOAD lists words from when they are first in "wide use": the NOAD is from the same publishers as OED and I doubt their editorial policies differ that much. If the question is "when did the phrase originate?" then an answer to "when did the word gain wide use?" is not a good answer. Why the NOAD lists 1970s is a mystery, however.

Comment: @Seamus: It is also a mystery why you down vote an answer just because it reports what reported from a different dictionary.

Comment: @kiamlaluno the dictionary is _wrong_ to claim the origin of the term is the 1970s. I'm not downvoting because you use a different dictionary, I'm downvoting because this is the _wrong answer_ to the question that was asked.

Comment: @Seamus: If you look at the question, it is tagged with _etymology_; therefore, I reply with what the NOAD reports in its "ORIGIN" notes. If you claim that the NOAD is wrong only because it says something different than the OED, then you are not taking so much to prove it's the NOAD to be wrong.

Comment: @kiamlaluno As someone who has studied philosophy of science I _know_ that Kuhn uses "paradigm shift" in _Structure of Scientific Revolutions_ so I know the phrases dates back to at least 1962. I'm not basing my knowledge on what the OED says: I'm basing it on weeks spent reading Kuhn and about Kuhn. [Corroboration from google books](http://books.google.com/books?id=xnjS401VuFMC&printsec=frontcover&dq=structure+of+scientific+revolutions&hl=en&ei=8cZ3TYefF4SJhQeRq636Bg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=paradigm%20shift&f=false)

Comment: @Seamus: Then you should correct the NOAD, and the OED, as even the OED reports the same origin of the word: "1970s: term used in the writings of Thomas S. Kuhn (1922–96), philosopher of science". Clearly you give to the word _origin_ a different meaning than the one given from a dictionary. As far as I concerned, when a question is tagged with _etymology_, I will report what I read on a dictionary, not when the word was first used in a book.

Comment: @kiamlaluno The [OED I looked at](http://oed.com/view/Entry/137329?redirectedFrom=paradigm%20shift#eid31854268) rightly points at Kuhn (1962) as the origin. What do you think origin means? It certainly doesn't mean "the point at which something became widely used". As I said before, I believe it is typical for dictionaries to try and find the first documented use of a word. This fits with my understanding of what "origin" means.

Comment: @Seamus: I believe that the [Oxford Dictionaries](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_gb0603850#m_en_gb0603850) reports the sentence I have written before. Just to state it, what I reported in my answer is not what I believe to be true, but what reported by a dictionary.

Comment: @kiamlaluno _why_ would you report something you don't believe to be true? "some source I don't trust said X" is not a good answer to a question.

Comment: @Seamus: I didn't say I don't believe it is true; I said I report not what I believe in, but what I find reported in a dictionary. The difference is that what somebody believes in can also be not true, not exact, or not correct; for example, I can say I believe you down voted this answer for reasons you didn't say, but that could also be not true. As a matter of fact, in my answer (and in my comments) I have never said I don't trust the NOAD. It seems to me that it's you who doesn't trust the NOAD.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I don't. Because it looks like in this instance they are wrong. And therefore I think your answer is wrong.

Comment: @Seamus: You would not remove the down vote even if I would remove what the NOAD reports. In a comment here, I reported a link to a free accessible site that reports what the NOAD reports too, but it doesn't seem that made a difference. I think that "it looks" is then rather subjective. I wonder why there is no down votes  for an answer that reports "paradigm shift" was used before 1960s.

Comment: @kiamlaluno You _really_ want that reputation back that much? That seems a little petty... Given the other answers to this question, I don't think your answer is really adding anything. If you want your rep back you can delete your answer.

Comment: First, my answer was one of the first answers; second, deleting an answer doesn't restore the lost points; third, you are not going to convince me you down voted this answer for an objective reason (and no, you are not going to convince me you down voted the NOAD). By the way, do you think that finding the truth means to remove anything that says something different from what you believe correct?